# git: what is a commit object inside a tree?

Tags: git, libgit2

While working on [gitmod](https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod), I noticed that the old root_tree is not being discarded when I stop using it. After tracking what was going on, I noticed that there's an object inside a tree that is not a blob or another tree. It's a `commit` object. This is from git's repo:

```
$ git ls-tree v2.28.0 | grep sha1col
160000 commit 855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2  sha1collisiondetection
```

I need to add support for it so that it is managed correctly but I was wondering what it represents. Because I was trying to get information about the object and it's not in my repo:

```
$ git cat-file -p 855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2
fatal: Not a valid object name 855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a submodule.  You can see that the path (`sha1collisiondetection`) is indexed in the `.gitmodules` file in the root of the repository:

```
[submodule "sha1collisiondetection"]
    path = sha1collisiondetection
    url = https://github.com/cr-marcstevens/sha1collisiondetection.git
    branch = master
```

The submodule repository will be included at its commit
855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2.  If you `git submodule update` that submodule, you'll see that it fetches that commit.

```
Submodule path 'sha1collisiondetection': checked out '855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2'
```

And inside that path, you can `cat-file` that commit.

```
% git cat-file -p 8558
tree c963fb3e40e0b9a031ffbab4f2f06bfbcc8527b7
parent 16033998da4b273aebd92c84b1e1b12e4aaf7009
author Michael Osipov <michael.osipov@siemens.com> 1557389728 +0200
committer Marc Stevens <cr-marcstevens@users.noreply.github.com> 1557396519 +0200

Detect endianess on HP-UX

HP-UX is not properly detected and classified as little endian. Add test macro
for HP-UX to make it big endian.
```